# house keeping gene variation under treatment

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, pcr

I am injecting BCG in mice ears to measure the local inflamation response in the infection side, one ear in the same mouse is kept as control by injecting PBS, in the other one, BCG is injected. When I do a qPCR the house keeping gene comes out later in the BCG ears compared to PBS control (even I measure RNA and DNA concentrations to have the same amount of materia). Does it means I have less amount of material in the PBS injected ear? or could it be the expression of the house-keeping gene is afected by BCG infection? Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What house keeping gene are you using as a control?

Comment: I tried 3, Gapdh, bactin and hprt, and always appears the same problem, the ears infected with BCG all the house keeping genes is shown to appear at less cycles compares to the ears injected with PBS.